# using javascript how to check string contains hindi font?

Tags: javascript, jquery

I am uploading a file using input type file I want to check that the name contains hindi font or english font.

Below is my code.

```
<!doctype html>
<html>
    <head>
        <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.12.2/jquery.min.js"></script>
        <script>
            $("document").ready(function () {

                $("#upload").change(function () {
                    var filename = $(this).val().replace(/^.*[\\\/]/, '')
                    alert(filename);

                });
            });
        </script>
    </head>
    <body>
        <div>
            <input type="file" name="upload" id="upload" value="upload" />
        </div>

    </body>
</html>
```

Comment: you cant get from font whether it is Hindi or English

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Hindi characters' character code is from **2309** to **2361**.

try this

```
function hasHindiCharacters(str)
{
  return str.split("").filter( function(char){ 
    var charCode = char.charCodeAt(); return charCode >= 2309 && charCode <=2361;
  }).length > 0;
}
```

You can use this method

```
hasHindiCharacters("अasd"); //outputs true

hasHindiCharacters("asd"); //outputs false
```

**DEMO**

```js
    function hasHindiCharacters(str)
    {
      return str.split("").filter( function(char){ 
        var charCode = char.charCodeAt(); return charCode >= 2309 && charCode <=2361;
      }).length > 0;
    }


    console.log(hasHindiCharacters("अasd")); //outputs true

    console.log(hasHindiCharacters("asd")); //outputs false
```

Answer (score 2):

You should be able to loop through each of the characters in the file name. Within the loop, use filename.charCodeAt(index) to get the Unicode value of the character. Checking if the char value is between 0900 and 097F which contains all the characters in the [Devanagari Unicode block](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Devanagari_(Unicode_block)) should tell you if it's using Hindi.